# Something going wrong with my java code

Tags: java, swing, jframe

When I am trying to print out two separate words into the console, using if statements, it only returns one word all the time, no matter what is entered.

My full code:

```
public class Frame{

    //Declaring needed text variables

    //Text Pane
    static JFormattedTextField formattedTextField = new JFormattedTextField();
    static String username = formattedTextField.getText();

    //Frame
    static JFrame UsernameFrame = new JFrame("Welcome");

    /**
     * @wbp.parser.entryPoint
     */
    public static void frame(){

        /**
         * Configuring the Frame
         */
        UsernameFrame.setSize(400,150);
        UsernameFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        UsernameFrame.getContentPane().setLayout(null);

        /**
         * Configuring Submit button
         */
        JButton btnSubmit = new JButton("Submit");
        btnSubmit.setBounds(0, 89, 384, 23);
        btnSubmit.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                if(username.length() < 5){
                    System.out.println("no");
                }
                if(username.length() > 5){
                    System.out.println("continue");
                }
                //Execute when the button is pressed
                System.out.println("The button has been pressed");
            }
        });
        UsernameFrame.getContentPane().add(btnSubmit);

        /**
         * Configuring user-name text pane
         */
        JLabel lblEnterYourSelected = new JLabel("Enter your selected username below");
        lblEnterYourSelected.setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
        lblEnterYourSelected.setBounds(81, 11, 214, 14);
        UsernameFrame.getContentPane().add(lblEnterYourSelected);

        /**
         * Configuring content pane
         */
        formattedTextField.setBounds(129, 36, 120, 20);
        UsernameFrame.getContentPane().add(formattedTextField);
        UsernameFrame.setVisible(true);




    }
}
```

Here is the specific line I'm working with

```
if(username.length() < 5){
  System.out.println("no");
}
if(username.length() > 5){
  System.out.println("continue");
}
```

I have looked a great deal for a solution and I just cannot find one.

Comment: Length in java is NOT broken!

Comment: um.. alright then..  Whats the problem..?

Comment: I'm confused as to how your code is reading in the value of username. Why is username a static variable?

Comment: I'm not sure..  I couldn't think of a better way to do it

Comment: Would you inline your code on the site?

Comment: "My full code is pasted here"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to read the value of the username AFTER the button has been pressed, in that case it will take the latest value entered and check for the length.

if you declare as below

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
            String username = formattedTextField.getText();

                if(username.length() < 5){
                    System.out.println("no");
                }
                if(username.length() > 5){
                    System.out.println("continue");
                }
                //Execute when the button is pressed
                System.out.println("The button has been pressed");
            }
```

this will work.
Also you have to include the condition to test if the length is equal to 5.

Comment: Thanks a whole bunch!